# Getting the value of no grouping column

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I know the basics in SQL programming and I know how to apply some tricks in SQL Server in order to get the result set, but I don't know all tricks in Oracle.

I have these columns:

```
col1   col2   col3
```

And I wrote this query

```
SELECT 
    col1, MAX(col3) AS mx3 
FROM 
    myTable 
GROUP BY 
    col1
```

And I need to get the value of col2 in the same row where I found the max value of col3, do you know some trick to solve this problem?

Comment: Treat the above as a common table expression or as an inline view and join it back to the base table to get your added columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of different ways to do this:

In both cases I'm treating your initial query as either a common table expression or as an inline view and joining it back to the base table to get your added column.  The trick here is that the INNER JOIN eliminates all the records not in your max query.

```
SELECT A.*,
FROM myTable A
INNER JOIN (SELECT col1 , MAX( col3 ) AS mx3 FROM myTable GROUP BY col1) B
 on A.Col1=B.Col1
and B.mx3 = A.Col3
```

or

```
with CTE AS (SELECT col1 , MAX( col3 ) AS mx3 FROM myTable GROUP BY col1)
SELECT A.*
FROM MyTable A
INNER JOIN CTE
 on A.col1 = B.Col1
and A.col3= cte.mx3
```

Comment: I was thinking in the same solution, using an INNER JOIN but as i dont know all the tricks and functions in ORACLE, i was sure there was another trick that it could help me, Thanks ! ! Regards ! ! !

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this, IMHO, is not to use `max`, but the window function `rank`:

```
SELECT col1 , col2, col3
FROM   (SELECT col1, col2, col3, 
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col3 DESC) rk
        FROM myTable) t
WHERE  rk = 1
```

BTW, the same syntax should also work for MS SQL-Server and most other modern databases, with MySQL being the notable exception.

Comment: I think this is not the best solution. I have millions of rows and the query takes too much time. I've used this same solution in SQL SERVER, but i decided to change it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative that's just a slight extension of your existing group by query (ie. doesn't require querying the same table more than once):

```
with mytable as (select 1 col1, 1 col2, 1 col3 from dual union all
                 select 1 col1, 2 col2, 2 col3 from dual union all
                 select 1 col1, 1 col2, 3 col3 from dual union all
                 select 1 col1, 3 col2, 3 col3 from dual union all
                 select 2 col1, 10 col2, 1 col3 from dual union all
                 select 2 col1, 23 col2, 2 col3 from dual union all
                 select 2 col1, 12 col2, 2 col3 from dual)
SELECT 
    col1,
    MAX(col2) keep (dense_rank first order by col3 desc) mx2,
    MAX(col3) AS mx3 
FROM 
    myTable 
GROUP BY 
    col1;

      COL1        MX2        MX3
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          3          3
         2         23          2
```